# Reducing the Build time - Hudson

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous-deployment

I would like to know,If there is a Hudson plugin to reduce the build time by distributing the tests across slaves.

I found a project called [Test Load Balancer (TLB)](https://github.com/test-load-balancer/tlb)

But this is used for only Ant projects. Mine is a Maven project. I'm looking for a solution on Hudson.

I'm trying to improve the build pipeline , so that we can move towards continuous delivery.
Right now, one of my Job takes 30 minutes on average.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am one of the creators of the Test Load Balancer - http://test-load-balancer.github.com. You are right, we only support Ant and Twist as of now in Java. However, it should be fairly easy to add support to Maven. The reason its not done yet is mostly because of bandwidth issues.

Can you please give a little more specifics on how you use Maven so that it will help us add Maven support into TLB?

The ideal thing would be if you can paste the build script snippet that actually runs your tests here. That will give us information about the maven plugin that you are using to run tests, how you use it etc.

We also have a card for the same on our issue tracker from a long time ago: http://code.google.com/p/tlb/issues/detail?id=1

You can refer to this and add details there as well if you wish and track progress there.

Pavan

Comment: Thanks Pavan. We use maven surefire plugin. I think you can find script online.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out. Also, would it be possible for you to give using the maven ant-run plugin? That way, you can just write your test task in an ant file and call that out. I know its far less than ideal, but its worth a shot.

Comment: Okay. I can give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Have posted the necessary changes as a patch to upstream. 
Merge request: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-726

Once a version with preprocessor feature merged in comes out we'll publish a TLB build that bundles maven support.

Wiring it up will just be about 5 lines worth of changes in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I read about some one setting up a Hudson server on a Linux ramdisk. 
**Their whole build was in memory.**

They got incredible performance improvements in their build time because most builds are IO bound. I'll see if I can find the article.

Comment: We tried that, and it was disappointing but we are messaging IO and CPU bound often..